# On Heroku, why is www causing a 'redirected you too many times' error while random subdomains work correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've just pushed a new app to a Heroku staging environment for the first time, and am getting a strange `redirected you too many times` error in the browser. How should I go about debugging this, and determining whether this is an issue in the app or an issue with the DNS records.

Some background - this is a multitenancy app, with subdomains for different users/ accounts. The app checks if the subdomain is recognized, and if not redirects to the root. As I had trouble configuring Heroku and my DNS provider for a root domain, I am using 'www'.

```
application_controller.rb
helper_method :subdomain, :current_account
before_filter :validate_subdomain
def current_account
  @current_account ||= Account.where(subdomain: subdomain.to_s ).first
end

def subdomain
  request.subdomain
end

def has_unrecognized_subdomain
  subdomain.present? && %w(www admin api).exclude?( subdomain ) && current_account.nil?
end

def validate_subdomain
  if has_unrecognized_subdomain
    redirect_to root_url( :subdomain => 'www' )
  end
end
```

I've added the root domain and subdomains to Heroku

```
heroku domains:add example.com
heroku domains:add *.example.com
```

and configured my DNS records

```
*   CNAME   myapp.herokuapp.com
```

My logs were showing the following

```
Filter chain halted as :validate_subdomain rendered or redirected
```

and so I disabled the `redirect_to` part of `validate_subdomain` to investidate further.

Now, if I include a random subdomain in the URL, the page is rendered correctly in the browser. But if I include 'www' I get a browser error. In Chrome:

```
The page isn’t working
www.example.com redirected you too many times.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Nothing is added to my logs when visiting a 'www' url, whereas logs are added with any other random subdomain string.

I would be very grateful for a sanity check - does this sound like a DNS issue rather than an app issue? And if so, are the CNAME records where I should be looking?